# Getting a list of objects in a JSON file (Java)

Tags: java, json

So I have a JSON file like this:

```
{"objects": { 
             "abc": {
                     "hash": "123",
                     "size": 7268
                    },
             "dbc": {
                     "hash": "321",
                     "size": 5376
                    },
              "wat": {
                      "hash": "121",
                      "size": 141671
                     }
              }
}
```

I have to get all the objects (abc, dbc & wat) and get the `hash` and `size` of it so it will return something like this:

```
abc, 123, 7268
dbc, 321, 5376
wat, 121, 141671
```

Comment: This is nested `JsonObject` not an `json-array` Thanks

Comment: First you should show, what all things you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson lib.
Gson gson = new Gson();
 gson.fromJson(..)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is use ObjectMaper from jackson-databind

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.readValue("jSonString", MyObject.class);
```

Package source: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.1.4